# Project File Line Suppression State Error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new with xamarin, i am getting an error:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added : Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat; SmartTweet.Android

I think it is a compatibility issue. Reinstall all the packages, but that not solved the error.

Also go to package manager console and run Update-Package -reinstall(which also reinstall and update all the packages)

I don't know what is the real problem. It already destroy my 2 days.

My packages.config files are adding below:

Portable packages.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <packages>
      <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Microsoft.CSharp" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Plugin.CurrentActivity" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Plugin.Permissions" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.AppContext" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Console" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Globalization.Calendars" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.IO.Compression.ZipFile" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.IO.FileSystem" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.3" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Net.Sockets" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.ObjectModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Reflection.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Runtime.Handles" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Text.RegularExpressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Threading.Timer" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="System.Xml.XmlDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Xam.Plugin.Connectivity" version="3.0.3" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Xam.Plugin.Media" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Xam.Plugins.Forms.ImageCircle" version="1.8.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Xamarin.Build.Download" version="0.4.3" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
      <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.4.270" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
    </packages>
```

Android packages.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <packages>
      <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
      <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
      <package id="Xam.Plugin.Connectivity" version="3.0.3" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
      <package id="Xam.Plugin.Media" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
      <package id="Xam.Plugins.Forms.ImageCircle" version="1.8.1" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
      <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.4.270" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
    </packages>
```

Anybody please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Solved by remove all the packages and reinstall again. Also unload and reload all projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by remove all the packages and reinstall again. Also unload and reload all projects.